# Front-end login problem: requires re-authorization when accessing dashboard

Tags: login, front-end

I have created front-end login form that allows users to login from front-end. However, when trying to access Admin section (dashboard), WP's default login form is displayed and user authorization is required.

```
$user_arr = array( 'user_login' => $u_name, 'user_password' => $u_pass, 'remember' => $u_remember );
$sign_user_on = wp_signon( $user_arr, true );
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I've got it! According to wp codex, second parameter of wp_signon() function refers to whether to use auth cookie or not. So if you use

```
wp_signon( $user_arr, false );
```

...re-auth will not be required.

Comment: If that fixes the problem, mark your own answer as accepted to close out the question.

Comment: I would but 1 day time frame is required.